# Detecting input change in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using jquery `.change` on an `input` the event will only be fired when the input loses focus

In my case, I need to make a call to the service (check if value is valid) as soon as the input value is changed. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: what kind of input? textbox? checkbox? radio? textarea? 
let's see what you've come up with so far

Comment: Sorry, its a input of type text. And as I said, I have tried change but this does not fire the way I need(for every change on the text in the input). I have also tried keydown but to get this working I will have to keep track off if the input is "dirty" or not.

Comment: if they are pressing a key, it's going to change 99% of the time,  you could always do a check for the keys that wouldn't in the event handler.

Answer (score 566, accepted):

**UPDATED for clarification and example**

examples: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/5kpeJ/

**Method 1. `input` event**

In modern browsers use the [`input`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-input) event.  This event will fire when the user is typing into a text field, pasting, undoing, basically anytime the value changed from one value to another.

In jQuery do that like this

```
$('#someInput').bind('input', function() { 
    $(this).val() // get the current value of the input field.
});
```

starting with jQuery 1.7, replace `bind` with `on`:

```
$('#someInput').on('input', function() { 
    $(this).val() // get the current value of the input field.
});
```

**Method 2. `keyup` event**

For older browsers use the `keyup` event (this will fire once a key on the keyboard has been released, this event can give a sort of false positive because when "w" is released the input value is changed and the `keyup` event fires, but also when the "shift" key is released the `keyup` event fires but no change has been made to the input.).  Also this method doesn't fire if the user right-clicks and pastes from the context menu:

```
$('#someInput').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val() // get the current value of the input field.
});
```

**Method 3. Timer (`setInterval` or `setTimeout`)**

To get around the limitations of `keyup` you can set a timer to periodically check the value of the input to determine a change in value.  You can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to do this timer check.  See the marked answer on this SO question: [jQuery textbox change event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6139954/222714) or see the fiddle for a working example using `focus` and `blur` events to start and stop the timer for a specific input field

Comment: Could you explain more about this solution? How do I get the current value? An how do I get this to only run when changes is made to the current value?

Comment: input event? there is no input event in jQuery (yet)...http://stackoverflow.com/q/11189136/104380

Comment: For method 2 I usually bind to both keyup *and* change. That way in situations where input occurs without a keypress (like pasting) it will at least fire the event when the input loses focus.

Comment: Docs for "input" event: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-input

Comment: IE10/11 also react to 'input' if a placeholder is set. If you're expecting to judge the value of the input (eg, if val) it will break in IE10 and 11. No fix found yet.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/7Lbt8/2/

Comment: found this http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/5kpeJ/ useful, like tutorial for those three methods

Comment: You can subscribe to keyup and change event at the same time.
$("#txtZipCode").bind("keyup change", function (e) {
        showLocation($(this).val());
    });

Comment: You should add 4th options, Using MutationObserver (better performance then timer) you can listen to the 'value' attribute change

Comment: @AdiDarachi MutationObserver will track changes to DOM elements.  However, a user changing data in an input field does not trigger a MutationObserver change...I setup a test case, only a JS code change to the `innerText` or `value` attribute (simulating user input) will trigger a MutationObserver event https://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/04chgpws/1/ (see the console.log for MutationObserver event logging).  Do you have a different test case I can look at?

Comment: my assumption was wrong, after further investigation Mutation will trigger in the following situations. 1. JS code change the value of the input (as you mentioned) 2. on blur event from the input after value change. And DOSE NOT ANSWER THIS QUESTION.

Comment: Very nice, unfortunately in Drupal the input is disabled after first keyup or on input events.

Comment: @MikeM will the first technique work if the input is from a non-keyboard entity like a barcode scanner?

Comment: FYI: These events will fire with a blank value if the keyboard is used to select a date that is not valid. ie. Feb 30.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564568/html5-input-type-date-input-event-incorrectly-fires-with-empty-value/48564701#48564701

Answer (score 192):

If you've got HTML5:

- `oninput` (fires only when a change actually happens, but does so immediately)

Otherwise you need to check for all these events which might indicate a change to the input element's value:

- `onchange`
- `onkeyup` (**not** `keydown` or `keypress` as the input's value won't have the new keystroke in it yet)
- `onpaste` (when supported)

and maybe:

- `onmouseup` (I'm not sure about this one)

Comment: @naomik from my test it works for checkbox inputs; except IE/Edge. Some other exceptions may appear, but it's smarter to use onchange for those input types(IMHO).

Answer (score 89):

With HTML5 and without using jQuery, you can using the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input):

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    console.log('input changed to: ', input.value);
});
```

This will fire each time the input's text changes.

Supported in IE9+ and other browsers.

Try it live in a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/eqemx218/).

Comment: Additional, [IE 9 does not fire an input event when the user deletes characters from an input (e.g. by pressing Backspace or Delete, or using the "Cut" operation)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event).

Comment: 'change' only fires on blur, not when the text changes. Use 'input' event to detect text changes.

Answer (score 15):

As others already suggested, the solution in your case is to **sniff multiple events**.
Plugins doing this job often listen for the following events:

```js
$input.on('change keydown keypress keyup mousedown click mouseup', handler);
```

If you think it may fit, you can add `focus`, `blur` and other events too.
I suggest not to exceed in the events to listen, as it loads in the browser memory further procedures to execute according to the user's behaviour.

***Attention:** note that changing the value of an input element with JavaScript (e.g. through the jQuery `.val()` method) won't fire any of the events above.*
(Reference: https://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: i also recommend to add focusout to avoid problems with autocomplete

Comment: I see. I searched, and focusout seems to be supported only by IE and partially by Chrome, am I right?

Comment: Just as a mild addition, To fire the event from jQuery you can call the corresponding action after `.val()` e.g for a change event on an input field, you would do something like this...  `$('#element').val(whatever).change()`

Answer (score 3):

// .blur is triggered when element loses focus

```
$('#target').blur(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

// To trigger manually use:

```
$('#target').blur();
```

Comment: .change is as I said only thrown when the inout loses focus and the value is changed, I need to get a even as soon as the input(text) is changed (as soon as the text in the input is changed). Blur will only trigger when the input loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the event to be fired whenever something is changed within the element then you could use the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event.

Comment: Okay but is this not more or less the same as the keydown? I will have to check if the input is "dirty" myself?

Comment: @SnowJim if you only want to do stuff when the input actually changes, you've got to either use `onchange`, or track the state yourself.  `keydown` doesn't work because it fires _before_ the input's state gets changed.

Comment: @Alnitak exacly and thats why I asking the question here. The onchange is not working, is it only thrown when leaving the input.

Comment: The elephant in the room of course is mobile. Pretty sure no keyboard or mouse events are going be of much use there. :p

Comment: @Askdesigners Keyup/down events should still work in the same fashion on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

There are jQuery events like **keyup** and **keypress** which you can use with input HTML Elements.
You could additionally use the **blur()** event.

Comment: .change is as I said only thrown when the inout loses focus and the value is changed, I need to get a even as soon as the input(text) is changed (as soon as the text in the input is changed). Blur will only trigger when the input loses focus.

Comment: you can't reliably check an input's value during a `keypress` event because the pressed key won't have changed that value yet.

Answer (score 0):

This covers every change to an input using jQuery 1.7 and above:

```
$(".inputElement").on("input", null, null, callbackFunction);
```