# Code Event Listener for form text fields when value changes?

Tags: javascript, forms, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have an html form with seven text fields. I need a Javascript event listener to listen for any change in value from the default value. The event listener needs to fire a function called format() no matter whether text is pasted, dropped or typed. How would I do this?

Below is the html form:

```
<form class="right_aligned" name="form" method="get" action="" id="form" >

<div style="float: left;"><input ondblclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="publication" value="Publication..." id="publication" style="border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;width:225px;padding:4px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;color: #000;"
ondrop="format()" ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}"     onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}"></div>

<div style="float: left;"><input ondblclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="title" value="Article Title..." id="title" style="border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;width:225px;padding:4px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;color: #000;"  
onmouseup="format()" ondrop="format()" ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}"></div>

<div style="float: left"><input ondblclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="author" value="Author..." id="author" style="border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;width:225px;padding:4px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;color: #000;"  
onmouseup="format()" ondrop="format()" ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}"></div>

<div style="float: left;"><input ondblclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="credentials" value="Credentials..." id="credentials" style="border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;width:225px;padding:4px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;color: #000;"  
onmouseup="format()" ondrop="format()" ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}"></div>

<div style="float: left"><input ondblclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="date" value="Date..." id="date" style="border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;width:225px;padding:4px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;color: #000;"  
onmouseup="format()" ondrop="format()" ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}"></div>

<div style="float: left;"><input ondblclick="this.value=''" type="textarea" name="evidence" value="Evidence..." id="evidence" style="border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;width:225px;padding:4px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;color: #000;"  
onmouseup="format()" ondrop="format()" ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}"></div>

<div style="float: left;"><input ondblclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="tagline" value="Tagline..." id="tagline" style="border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;width:225px;padding:4px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px;color: #000;"  
onmouseup="format()" ondrop="format()" ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}"></div>

<input class="button" type="reset" value="Clear Form" onClick="clearForm()" style="margin:5px 5px 5px 10px;float:left">

</form>
```

By the way, the event listener code only has to work in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely best to just use the *change* event. It will be dispatched when the input loses focus, which is the appropriate time.

The code seems very verbose, it really needs to be cleaned up:

```
<div style="float: left;">
```

Style should be added using CSS to reduce the amount of markup in the page. It also makes controlling styles easier as they're all in one place and can be controlled from a stylesheet.

```
<input ondblclick="this.value=''"
```

Are users expecting that? Double clicking on a text input usually selects the word under the cursor, users might be surprised when it deletes the content.

```
type="text" name="tagline" value="Tagline..." id="tagline"
style="..."
```

Again, all that style stuff can be in a stylesheet so you have one rule applied to all similar inputs using class or some other selector.

```
onmouseup="format()" ondrop="format()"
```

Do you think all these events might get in each other's way?

```
ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}"
```

Should that happen? What if the user is on their way to another input - drag over this one and - oops! - content's gone!

```
onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}"
onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}">
```

I think you can replace all but the above two handlers with a single *onchange* handler that calls *format()*.

For example, if you put the style into CSS rules like:

```
#form input {
  border:1px solid;
  border-color:#B0B0B0;
  width:225px;
  padding:4px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  color: #000;
}

#form div {
  float: left;
}
```

and add a function to handle the hint like:

```
function updateHint(e) {
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (e.type == 'focus') {
    if (el.value == el.defaultValue) {
      el.value='';
      el.style.color='#000';
    }
  } else if (e.type == 'blur') {
    if(el.value=='') {
      el.value = el.defaultValue;
      el.style.color='#000';
    }
  }
}
```

Then your input can be:

```
<div>
  <input onchange="format(this);" type="text"
   name="publication" value="Publication..."
   onchange="format(this)"
   onfocus="updateHint(event);" 
   onblur="updateHint(event);">
</div>
```

You might want to look at adding the handlers dynamically as listeners, but inline is fine if this is all you are doing.

Comment: The problem with the change event, is that the textfield must lose focus. I don't want that, I am looking for a solution to listen for any type of user input and update right away.

Comment: You must use the change event as that is the only time that you know that the user has (possibly) finished updating the element. To be certain you need to wait for submit. How will you know sooner? Even if they drag something into the input, they may still want to modify it before going on. And formatting as the user types is a hideous un–usability feature that annoys the heck out of users.

Comment: Actually, the project I am working on is not for a website, but rather an extension. The whole purpose of this form is to format the text. I would like it to update in real time, eliminating the hassle of a submit or go button, since the user just wants the final result. Also, it is not submitting the form, rather it prints out the formatted text in a contenteditable div below the form, so the user can always go back and edit the form fields.

Comment: This was a loooooooong time ago, and since then my knowledge of technologies has become more thorough and less "hacky" I look at it now totally agree with RobG's excellent points. And the use of `onchange` makes a lot of sense. I don't quite remember what I was trying to do, but the great suggestions make this the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This would be really easy to do with a library like jquery

example:

```
$("form input").change(function(){
    format();
});
```

Comment: Again, it relies on the fact that the textfield must lose focus. I don't want that, I am looking for a solution to listen for any type of user input and update right away.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been discussed previously (I can't find the previous questions right now).  The native DOM doesn't support what you want (as you know, it only fires when focus leaves).  That leaves two main choices:

1. Try to intercept all possible events connected with the ways that the content could change by the user (keys, mouse right click paste, drag/drop, etc...) and then check the content yourself after each possible event to see if anything has changed.
2. Use a moderately slow timer to poll the value in every field to see if they have changed.

I'm generally not a fan of of timer solutions as they seem CPU-inefficient, but it might be possible to do a reasonably efficient timer that was user friendly if it was coordinated with typing so the format would fire x seconds after typing pauses.

**Edit:** I found one of those [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event).  According to that, three possible ways "input" event, hook all regular events (like keyup) or timer.