# Selecting from a drop down ( browser cached drop down ) - which event gets triggered?

Tags: javascript, browser, event-handling, dom-events

**Gist**

Which event gets triggered when we select from a dropdown which is populated from the cache ( such as usernames and other form values ) in a `<input type="text">` .

**Detailed**

In a form, we can login with multiple username say `A`,`B`,`ABC` . And the browser caches all these values ( w.r.t password remember ). So,if we try to login with `A` - a drop down pops up giving multiple option say `A` , `ABC`  -- which event gets triggered once we select any of the options provided.

`oninput, onchange, onblur`  -- none of which seems to get triggered if we select from browser provided drop down.

Help,
Beginner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [these](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) events with select. 
Cache has nothing to do with the drop down.

What you need is depending on your use.

Generally `onchange` is used to get the value or call a function when the value changes.

`onblur` would trigger a function when the drop down losses focus. eg, when you use `tab` or other methods.

Comment: i've clearly mentioned its not `select` on which i'm working on!!.. its on `input textbox`.See the question and answer!!

Comment: I got the `input textbox` but my answer according to your question says    Which event gets triggered when `we` select from a dropdown ..... in a <input type="text"> . So my answers says it depends on what u want to use.. Am i missing something?

Comment: i know what `onchange` and `onblur` does.. and not using `select` tag.. its the normal drop down that comes on textbox for usernames ( gmail/facebook/twitter and many other major sites - their usernames will be cached by the browser ).. that's what i want,not the select tag!!

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here: [On input change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event)

> In modern browsers use the input event. This event will fire when the user is typing into a text field, pasting, undoing, basically anytime the value changed from one value to another.

Comment: Have you tested it?, has you seen it work?. The question is "browser fed data addition - event".

Comment: Indeed, I have tested it. I never post an answer without first testing it. Like you, I was looking for this same solution. First stumbled on your question and saw that the previous answer did not work. Then found the one that I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

easily use select event

example:

$('#test').***select***(function(){ alert('data changed'); });