# Handle on numeric changed event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, telerik

I am trying to learn JavaScript.
I use a numeric textbox from Telerik for setting a quantity, that will be used in my JavaScript code.

I managed to call a function on `keyup` of that numeric textbox, the function does a small calculation like: UnitPrice * Quantity, and fills another textbox with the result of this calculation.

Since it is a numeric textbox, it has an *increase* and *decrease* button on it.(See below)
[image: Numeric TextBox]

My code works when modifying the value manually, but it doesn't work when increasing or decreasing the value with the up and down buttons.

I tried adding the following lines to my Javascript code, but that stops the numeric textbox from working.(nothing happens on increasing and decreasing using buttons.)

```
$("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Quantity)").onclick(OnQuantityChanged);
```

And

```
$("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Quantity)").onchange(OnQuantityChanged);
```

Next is my Javascript code that works when updating manually:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        //Call OnQuantityChanged, when page has been refreshed.
        OnQuantityChanged();
        //Call OnQuantityChanged, on keyup event.
        $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Quantity)").keyup(OnQuantityChanged);
    });

    //OnQuantityChanged event, multiplies quantity by unitPrice INCL. and unitPrice EXCL. for filling total value INCL. and EXCL.
    function OnQuantityChanged()
    {
        var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Quantity)").value);
        if (quantity != null)
        {
            var unitPriceInclTax = parseFloat(document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.UnitPriceInclTax)").value);
            var unitPriceExclTax = parseFloat(document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.UnitPriceExclTax)").value);
            var SubTotalInclTax = String(quantity * unitPriceInclTax);
            var SubTotalExclTax = String(quantity * unitPriceExclTax);
            if (SubTotalInclTax != null)
            {
                @*document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalInclTax)").value = String(SubTotalInclTax);*@
                $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalInclTax)").val(String(Math.round(SubTotalInclTax*1000) / 1000));
            }
            if (SubTotalExclTax != null)
            {
                @*document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax)").value = String(SubTotalExclTax);*@
                $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax)").val(String(Math.round(SubTotalExclTax * 1000) / 1000));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The HTML of that page is below:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.UnitPriceInclTax):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UnitPriceInclTax)@Model.UnitPriceInclTax
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.UnitPriceExclTax):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UnitPriceExclTax)@Model.UnitPriceExclTax
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Quantity):
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.SubTotalInclTax):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubTotalInclTax, new { style="width:137px"})
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax,  new { style="width:137px" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

What event can I use to make the calculation update when the *increase* or *decrease* button is pressed? Or is there a different way to achieve this?

**Update**

I read that the `oninput` event can be used in HTML for getting the increase and decrease, so I added following code:

```
var quantityInput = document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Quantity)");
        quantityInput.oninput = function()
        {
            alert("i got called, yay");
            var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Quantity)").value);
            if (quantity != null) {
                var unitPriceInclTax = parseFloat(document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.UnitPriceInclTax)").value);
            var unitPriceExclTax = parseFloat(document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.UnitPriceExclTax)").value);
            var SubTotalInclTax = String(quantity * unitPriceInclTax);
            var SubTotalExclTax = String(quantity * unitPriceExclTax);
            if (SubTotalInclTax != null) {
                @*document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalInclTax)").value = String(SubTotalInclTax);*@
                $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalInclTax)").val(String(Math.round(SubTotalInclTax * 1000) / 1000));
            }
            if (SubTotalExclTax != null) {
                @*document.getElementById("@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax)").value = String(SubTotalExclTax);*@
                $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax)").val(String(Math.round(SubTotalExclTax * 1000) / 1000));
            }
        }
        }
        });
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189136/fire-oninput-event-with-jquery)

Problem is that code still isn't only called by changing number manually.

Comment: My guess would be to use [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onchange) rather than [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onkeyup)

Comment: I tried that, but it then doesn't update when increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle using the Telerik textBox that you speak of?

Comment: have you tried using onkeyup() and onchange() together?

Comment: @derylius code does the same when using them together, it updates when changing it manually, number increases and decreases correctly, but it doesn't update it's calculation.

Comment: `onchange` works with the standard HTML5 number input, see http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/RPXJK/

Comment: I tried adding in the onchange as said before, but the OnQuantityChanged function isn't even called, I checked that with adding a alert and it isn't showed.

Comment: Make a simple jsfiddle with the Telerik textBox that you are using.

Comment: Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/RPXJK/1/ I wasn't able to get the numeric to work, I will try to repair it.