# jQuery to change case on type for first name

Tags: jquery

I would like to normalise the first name of my users when the type it on an input field.

```
<input type="text" name="firstName">
```

So, when the user types:

- tommy, it should be corrected to Tommy.
- jean-claude, it should be corrected to Jean-Claude.

Is there a function to do this ?

This is what I tried:

```
new_str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(txtVal) {
    return txtVal.toUpperCase();
});
$('.list-title').text(new_str);
```

But it doesn't work for the second case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want your code to run whenever the user types something in, or when they click a button?

Comment: @bobjoe, when the user types please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS `text-transform` and regex

[**REGEX demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aA5qYa/1)

```js
function print() {
  let input = $('input').val().replace(/(?:^|[\s-])\w/g, function(str) {
    return str.toUpperCase()
  })

  console.log(input)
}
```

```css
input {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="firstName">
<button onclick="print()">print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on('input',)` event listener with jQuery. [on('input')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189136/fire-oninput-event-with-jquery)

```
$('.list-title').on('input', function(event) {
    str = $('.list-title').val();
    new_str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(txtVal) {
        return txtVal.toUpperCase();
    });
    $('.list-title').val(new_str);
});
```

This will automatically run your function anytime the user changes something

Answer (score 0):

Add One more step.

```
var new_str = "Jean-Claude";
new_str = new_str.toLowerCase().replace(/-[a-z]/g,function(txtVal){return txtVal.toUpperCase();});
new_str = new_str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g,function(txtVal){return txtVal.toUpperCase();});
console.log(new_str);
```