# JS Password conformation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple Register page which is :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label style="display: block; padding-left: 0.3em;">REGISTER</label>
        </div>

        <div class="emailInputDiv">
            <label class="email">Email </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="em">
        </div>

        <div class="passwordInputDiv">
            <label class="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="pw">
        </div>

        <div class="passwordInputDiv2">
            <label class="password">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="pw2">
        </div>

        <div style="margin-bottom: 0.5em">
            <button type="submit" class="signInButton" onclick="check()">
                <span>Sign In</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>


    <script>
        let pw = document.getElementById("pw").value;
        let pw2 = document.getElementById("pw2").value;
        (function () {
            if(pw != pw2){
                $('.passwordInputDiv').css("color", "red");
                $('.passwordInputDiv > input').css("color", "red");
                $('.passwordInputDiv2').css("color", "red");
                $('.passwordInputDiv2 > input').css("color", "red");
            }
        })();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanna make its font color red immediately whenever password inputs change and doesnt match. that self-executing function runs when page loads, but I want it to run everytime those inputs changes.

Also those pw and pw2 is empty since its executed when page is loaded. So fucntion does not execuded.

How can I adjust this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: What have you tried so far and what was the problem with your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a Javascript function on every input change you add `oninput='exampleJavascriptFunction()'` to the HTML element or use Javascript to add an event listener as explained below.

So your first password box:

```html
<input type="password" name="password" id="pw">
```

would become:

```html
<input type="password" name="password" oninput="check()" id="pw">
```

> Note: It is now better a better practice to use a javascript function to add an event listener.
>
> For example: `element.addEventListener([name], [callback])` with plain Javascript or `element.on([name], [callback])` with Jquery (which uses `addEventListener` internaly).

Adding the event listener with Jquery/Javascript:

```js
$("pw").on('input', check)
```

See [Jquery on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189136/fire-oninput-event-with-jquery) or [MDN input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Please don't suggest to use inline event handlers (`oninput="check()"` they really should not be used anymore since the release of IE 9 and even before that it was questionable to use them.

Comment: `Or using event listeners:` is misleading. All of them are event listeners. `oninput="check()"` is an event listener, `element.addEventListener` uses the web API to attach the event listener, and `$("pw").on('input', check)` uses jQuery to attach the event listener (jQuery itself uses (`addEventListener`) internally.

Comment: @t.niese I updated my post to try to make it more clear.