# Click on a div, add it to the search query input

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm basically trying to allow the user to click on a 'recent search tag' and add it to the search input in full. What I mean by 'in full' is the tags' styling along with text.

For example:

[image: When clicking on a recent search tag, add it to search.]

I know there's a jquery plugin for this. But I really wanted to know if there was a simple approach in getting this done.

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEr6m/9/). Right now when I click on the recent search tag, it takes the text of each div and one at a time.

```
$('.tag').click(function(e){
     var tag = $(this).children().html();
     $('input').val(tag);
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can not insert HTML into an input, although you can insert HTML into a contentEditable div pretending to be an input.

Comment: @Asad Thank you for the advice. I have another question. If the user clicks on one or more tags. How do I get each selected text to show within the search? Because as of right now I can only do one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the styled tags to show "in" the input box by placing them under the input (w/transparent bg) (similar to what Google does with their autocomplete functionality)

Setup some markup around the input (input wrapper and a container for the tags):

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="tag tag-input"></div>
    <input name="q" id="search" class="input-text" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="on" value="" />
</div>
```

Position the `tag-input` to be inline with the text, set the `input` to a wider `word-spacing` so the tags are spaced equally.  Set the `tag-input` `z-index` lower than the input's.  It'll also adjust the input width as the user types a long query.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/YEr6m/14/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/YEr6m/14/show))

This uses the `oninput` event (ala `$input.bind('input'...`) which works in modern browers (see [On input change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6458946/222714) for more info on that)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tag').click(function(e){
    var tag = $(this).children().html();
    $('input').val(function(i,v){return v+" "+tag});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

will add tags instead of replacing them.