# jquery on(change) doesn't work

Tags: jquery, onchange

The code below works great:

```
this.on('keypress', '[data-' + options.dataClass + ']', function () {
alert(1);
});
```

This also works for keydown, keyup, ... but the code below doesn't work

```
this.on('change', '[data-' + options.dataClass + ']', function () {
alert(1);
});
```

By the way the elements matching selector are input with type of text. what is wrong?

Edit: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5sUgr/)

Comment: From the jQuery website `The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.`

Comment: try this on a select, as arsenal stated, it'll work..not so much on a text, you need to harness focus..this.on('change','select',function(){
            alert(1);
        });

Comment: well it might work great for select but i need it for input

Comment: try this...this.on('input','[data-' + options.dataClass + ']', function() {
   alert(1);
})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `change` event only fires when the input is blurred (and there have been changes made since it gained focus). I think what you are looking for is the `input` event. This will trigger immediately whenever the input is changed by a keypress or paste.

Be warned that the `input` event only works on newer browsers.

[Documentation for input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input)

Comment: well if it is so. and If I want to have old browser support too, what should I do? take my plugin back to work with `keyup`? and is there a way to check if `input` is working in this browser or not?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani the way to replicate the `input` event is to bind to `paste`, `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`, and `dragdrop`. It is quite annoying to write. see other questions such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event)