# Edit text in HTML

Tags: html

I have an `h1` header on my page that simply says "Hello world".

I want to know how I can add a form to change the header to say "Hello world from *my_form_field_value*".

Comment: Use punctuation **PLEASE**. I don't understand **AT ALL** what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the technology you are using (jQuery, ASP(.NET), PHP, etc).

user3047190's answer used jQuery (client side solution). If using a server side solution, you can have the form send a querystring containing the text to the server and return a page with the text you just typed in.

Here's an online example: http://html.net/tutorials/asp/lesson11_ex1.asp

Here's the tutorial explaining the above classic ASP example: http://html.net/tutorials/asp/lesson11.asp

Answer (score 0):

This question is horribly phrased so I'm afraid I will answer your question with other answers.

What I believe you want is on input change, you want to capture the change ([Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event)) and update the h1 text: $("h1").text("newString");

(that will only work with jquery included)