# Listening to value change of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a textarea which changes value dynamically. For instance on events like this:

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
   $(this).val('some value');
});
```

I would like to alert each time the value changes:

```
$('textarea').on("input propertychange",function(){
    alert('he');
});
```

This doesn't work. I also tried Jquery `change` and `document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('propertychange'` and other things nothing seems to function. What else can I try?

[Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8wxLpov/)

Comment: Working fine for me > http://jsfiddle.net/e4e38kmm/

Comment: As far as I know programmatic changes do not trigger any events. You could do it manually : `$(this).val('some value').trigger("change");`

Comment: @James G Add some value dynamically like so `$('textarea').val('value');` you will see it doesn't work

Comment: Triggering the event handler manually is the only way to do that, other than a horrible interval or something like that.

Comment: @adeneo Yes intervals are horrible:)

Comment: @Quentin Hi, I don't understand the answer in the link, could you please tell me how to implement in the fiddle..?

Comment: @Youss — Ninsly has already given you the relevant code from that answer in a form that "just works" with your existing code.

Comment: @Quentin Yes I got it now:) thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, there is a keyup function you can use. Something like this:

```
$('#something').keyup(function(){
   //do what you want
  });
```

I also found this, and I think you can benefit from the answers here: 
[Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event)

Comment: This is not dynamically added value but on keyup...

Comment: The keyup event will not detect when JavaScript changes the value of the field (nor will the input event if we pay attention to the link-only portion of your answer). Demo of this failing to work: http://jsfiddle.net/1h8j2dqm/