# JQuery event on text changing

Tags: jquery

I try to detect text changing in live on an input text. Here is my attempt to do this :

This code is for JQuery includes version.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

This code is for the form. Like you will see, a simple form with 2 input text (id and password) and a button.

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="mail adress" />
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="login" />            
</form>
```

And finally the JQuery code that seems not working. I placed it in the `<body></body>` which also contains my form.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#id').on('input', function () {
        alert('text changed');
    });
</script>
```

This short code doesn't seems to work. I followed a [precedent question asked in this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event), but this solution didn't help me.

The most strange thing is that it works when I copy paste this code in a snippet, but doesn't with a simple html file located in my PC. So I think the problem come from my jquery includes, possibly..

May someone light my lantern ?

Comment: may be, you need to put in inside a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: This is exactly the solution. Thank you so much @Arun P Johny ! I'm putting the solution refering to you asap

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arun P Johny, the solution was to put my handler directly into the ready. Solution is the following so :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id').on('input', function () {
            alert('text changed');
        });
    });         
</script>
```