# What event to know when user has entered data into form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form. I want to enable/disable a button until user eneters text in one of the fields. I am adding an event attribute to the  which triggers some javascript. This javascript will enable/disable the button. 
 Problem is I can't figure out what event attribute to use. What event attribute please will trigger as soon as user enters data? I tried onchange but that only gets called when i clicked back outside the text area. So it may aswell be onblur.

Comment: For input html element, you can check for `onchange` event which will get fired once after fill and pressing enter...

Comment: why not use jquery and simplify life. its the norm now.. check this page for all form events. clean and precise explanation http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/

Comment: how about `onfocus` ?

Comment: onchange is only called after I finish entering text not whilst. Jquery just seems to be a bit unecessary seeing at HTML has event. onfocus means that the field can be empty when called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible events that can be used: either `onChange` or `onKeyPress`. `onChange` will trigger when the value of an input has changed while `onKeyPress` will trigger every time the user types something in a text box. The onChange triggers once the user has CHANGED something in the value, and got out of the input focus. That means the user has to hit TAB or click somewhere else for the event to trigger, hence why `onKeyPress` might be better suited.

Read more:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Younger browsers also support `onInput` which should certainly be prefered for now, if you do not need to support older browsers.

Comment: This worked and it answered the question. Which was 'what event attribute to use to know when user enters text?'. I used 'onKey'Press and voila. Im interested to know why it was down voted though?

Comment: It was down voted because onInput is simply prefered now... Until you face a user with IE8 or IE7 which I do everyday. Note that onkeypress will not trigger if the value is changed programatically (on a button click for example), so oninput would be better in that way... But onchange has also its strengths, and comes to support the 2 other events on select inputs, checkboxes and the like.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Im not too fussed about backwards browser support. I will to an extent but we have to draw the line somewhere. Update your browser or get a new computer I say.

Comment: @RyanForsyth I would still suggest using `onkeyup` since you may run into issues validating the input when they delete the values with backspace using `onkeypress` since the event triggers before the value changes.

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment so, here is a thorough explanation on stack, although it uses jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input`

```
function activateForm (event) {
    if(!this.value == ""){ 

    }
}
var input = document.querySelector(".myInput");

input.addEventListener("input", activateForm , false)
```