# cloning input text in a form

Tags: forms, clone

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td><td><input type="text" name="field1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bar</td><td><input type="text" name="field2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td><td><input type="text" name="field3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td><td><input type="text" name="field4" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td><td><input type="text" name="field5" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to insert text in field1 and automatically cloning it in all fields that are in foo rows. For example, if I insert "abcd" in field1, also field3 and field5 could be filled automatically with the same "abcd". Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery it can be done this way:

```
$("input[name='field1']").on("input change", function() {
    $("input[name='field3'],input[name='field5']").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: You can even make it shorter and use just 
"[name=field3],[name=field5]" instead of "input[name='field3'],input[name='field5']"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='field1']").keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
{
    $( "input[name^='field']" ).val($(this).val());
}
});
```

Comment: Please add at least a few lines of prose explaining how this works and why it solves the problem.  (And in this case you should also indicate that you're assuming jQuery.)