# Why the code does not works JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have Javascript code following below and could not get alert message why? How can I fix this? Thanks for all response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="date" id="mydate">
<p id="current"></p>

<script>
  document.getElementById('myDate').onchange = function () {
        var selectedDateFromCalendar = this.value;

        var currentdate = new Date();
        document.getElementById("current").textContent = currentdate.toUTCString();

        // get difference in milliseconds
        var Diff = Math.abs(currentdate.getTime() - selectedDateFromCalendar.getTime());

        // Convert it into days
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        alert(diffDays);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: case sensitive: `myDate` and `mydate`.  Also try changing `onchange` to `onkeydown`

Comment: thanks @user1790982 . But I could not get alert still :/

Comment: `selectedDateFromCalendar` is a string, so it has no `.getTime()` method. Open your browser's develoer console.

Comment: thanks @user1106925. I can fix it in this way  var Diff = new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate;

Comment: the answer to this kind of questions is **"Open the console"** - Most likely they have no idea what it is and if we provide just code fixes they'll stay oblivious to it's usefulness/purpose and ask another question later on that is just as basic as this one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to the `oninput` event. You could also check for `onchange` and other events. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6458949/1762224) is helpful.

Also, the date `<input>` has a `valueAsDate` property that returns a date object.

***Note:*** I used `console.log` rather than `alert`, because the Stack snippets do not allow `alert`.

```js
document.getElementById('myDate').oninput = function() {
  var selectedDateFromCalendar = this.value;
  var currentdate = new Date();

  document.getElementById("current").textContent = currentdate.toUTCString();

  // Get difference in milliseconds.
  var diff = Math.abs(currentdate.getTime() - this.valueAsDate.getTime());

  // Convert it into days.
  var diffDays = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

  console.log(diffDays);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myDate" />
<p id="current"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added your code a little bit and it is working perfectly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="date" id="mydate" onchange="dates()">
<p id="current"></p>

<script>

function dates () {
        var selectedDateFromCalendar = this.value;

        var currentdate = new Date();
        document.getElementById("current").textContent = currentdate.toUTCString();

        // get difference in milliseconds
        var Diff = Math.abs(currentdate.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime());

        // Convert it into days
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        alert(diffDays);
    }


</script>
</body>    
</html>
```