# How to constantly have access to HTML textbox through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a very simple form in HTML:

```
<form>
  Number: <input id="form" type="text" name="Number"/>
</form>
```

Then I have this JavaScript:

```
var n = document.getElementById("form").value;
//calculations with n
//later, it outputs another variable (steps) that comes from that value of n
```

I want it to work out so that whenever the user types anything into the textbox, it does all of the JavaScript code and outputs the `steps` without having any submit button or anything like that. So if the user is going to type 123, for example, when they type 1, it will output `steps` when calculated for 1, then when they type the 2, it will output `steps` when calculated for 12, then when the type the 3, it will output `steps` when calculated for 123.

Comment: [oninput](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event) may be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onInput` event:

```html
<input id="form" type="text" onInput="yourFunction();" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function yourFunction() {
    var n = document.getElementById("form").value;
}
```

[W3Schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)

---

Example:

```js
function yourFunction() {
        var n = document.getElementById("form").value;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
Input: <input id="form" type="text" name="Number" onInput="yourFunction();" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Inputs can be modified in other ways than the keyboard, e.g. pasting or dragging with the mouse.

Comment: It's true. Changed to `onInput`.

Answer (score 0):

Register an onkeypress event handler on the input element and let that handler do the calculation. Btw you don't need the form container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap the [input](http://devdocs.io/dom/globaleventhandlers/oninput) event, and run your code in response

```js
;(function(){
  "use strict";
  
  //  make sure the DOM is available
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

    //  function that does the work
    var calculateResult = function(event){
      o.value = n.valueAsNumber.toString(2);
    };    
    
    //  select the DOM elements
    var n = document.getElementById('n');
    var o = document.getElementById('o');
    
    //  attach your function to the input event
    n.addEventListener('input',calculateResult);
    
  });

})();
```

```html
<form id="f">
  Number: <input id="n" type="number" name="n"/>
</form>

Number As Binary:
<output form="f" for="n" id="o"></output>
```