# How to detect input field value change in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I will have N number of input fields and every field will have a value CHANGE without getting in or out of focus. How can I detect value change of every input field.

I only found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event) related and using that I tried following but it is not working. can Any one help further

```js
for (var i=0;i<$scope.customers.product.length;i++)
{
//i m trying to get unique ids and bining input fields for change 
$('#total-i').on('input', function() { 
    alert($(this).val()); // get the current value of the input field.
});
}
```

```html
//there will be multiple of input fields having unique ids
<input id="total-{{$index}}" value={{cust.price*cust.quantity}}"/>
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy and possible with `ng-change` provided you have `ng-model` associated to input.

```
<input id="total-{{$index}}" value={{cust.price*cust.quantity}}" ng-model="total" ng-change="updatemethod()"/>
```

`total and updatemethod()` should be part of controller `$scope`.

Comment: I need to either have value or ng-model in my input element. Using both does not displays blank output on my html page @Panomosh

Comment: why you need `value` to your input when `ng-model` is there in angular?, if you are using `jquery`, then use `$('#myContent').keyup(function() { ` or `.change()`

Comment: I am resolving an expression in my value and if I have to use ng-model then I have to change much of my LOCs and YES this is the only way out I too think.  and before that, I thought of asking for help here. Even before I was using a label here.  Getting into situation made me use input field and now i think making value to model will end the problem @anoop

Comment: @usman : Even if you use label for `{{cust.price*cust.quantity}}`, then also price and quantity should be part of `ng-model`. You need to have them inside ng-model then only you can utilize angular 2 way binding.

Comment: yes they are part of the model and i was trying to get their product in a label.  Which I achieved very well. Then i tried  to do something when label value changes. and that got me stuck to NO other way but to change it to model. :) whole story @anoop

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked in your question is not about Angular (it uses jQuery). Where is the ***Angular way*** to do it (considering you are showing inputs with `ng-repeat`):

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
    <input ng-model="i" ng-change="update(i)"/>
</div>
```

With this code, whenever you will update `i` (eg: when you will change the input value), the `update(i)` method will be triggered.

---

Here is a tiny example of what I'm explaining:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    
    $scope.update = function(item) {
        alert(item + ' has been changed!');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in items">
        <input type="text" ng-model="i" ng-change="update(i)"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This ng-change method works only when we focus in or out of the input field.  Whereas I am changing value of input field using expressions and values of expression variables are changed using other input fields present on my page. Therefore I reference that only question related to my problem

Comment: @Usman You can set a `watcher` on each variable to get change events.

Comment: can you tell me how to add a watcher by ID. As I am not having any specific variable name for that repeated input field but ID

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an object to associate with the ng-model and then watch it. Since you didn't provide a Codepen of fiddle instance to meddle with, I'm not sure this works, check it out.

```
//for each index
$.each(modelObject, function(key, value) {
   //set a watcher
   var watchString = "modelObject[" +key + "]";  
   $scope.$watch(watchString, function (newValue, oldValue) {
      $scope.update(modelObject[key]);
   });
});
```

Comment: if you are creating ng-model  for my input field and watching it. then the discussion ends.. Please read what my question is and what we all talked about on this question