# change recursive function variable 'onchange' with pure js

Tags: javascript

I have a page like this (body tag has `onload="doInit();"`):

```js
function doInit() {
    var end = new Date();
    var tday = new Date();

    var full = 540;
    end.setHours(18, 0, 0);

    function updateTime() {
        var now = new Date(),
     time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds(),
     remaining = end - now,

     _second = 1000,
     _minute = _second * 60,
     _hour = _minute * 60,
     _day = _hour * 24,

     lwidth = document.getElementById('rng').value,

     hours = Math.floor((remaining % _day) / _hour);
     minutes = Math.floor((remaining % _hour) / _minute);
     seconds = Math.floor((remaining % _minute) / _second);

     document.getElementById('remain').innerHTML = ' ';
     document.getElementById('remain').innerHTML += hours + 'h ';
     document.getElementById('remain').innerHTML += minutes + 'm ';
     document.getElementById('remain').innerHTML += (seconds + 1) + 's';

     var current = (full - (hours * 60) - minutes) / full * 100;
        document.getElementById('progress').style.height = lwidth;
     document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = current.toFixed(1) + '%';
     document.getElementById('progress').style.width = current + "%";

     setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
    }
    updateTime();
}

doInit();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#progress {
    height: 14px;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#remain {
    width: 100px;
    height: 14px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

#rng {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"> </div>
<div id="remain"></div>
<input id='rng' type="range" name="" min="10" max="20" value="15" step="1">
```

`updateTime()` function updates the remain time, shows the current progress and checks the input range value for setting progressbar height. But I don't want it to check the input every second because the progressbar height is not often changed, so it's not necessary. I want the height to be changed when I change the input range value, but not checking the value every second.

P.S. also I'd like the height to be changed instantly (not wainting a second for updateTime to be called).

Comment: Your formatting is a little crazy, you'll probably do better if this was easier to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery)

Comment: I'd like not to use jQuery, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the height to be changed when I change the input range value

The value you want to change in the `onchange` listener is not used or needed in your recursion. Therefore, you can just use an event listener and handle changes outside the `updateTime` function.

I sanitised your code and added the listener:

```js
function doInit() {
 var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
 var remain = document.getElementById('remain');
 var range = document.getElementById('rng');
 
    var end = new Date();
    var full = 540;
    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
 
    end.setHours(18, 0, 0);

    function updateTime() {
        var now = new Date();
     var time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
     var remaining = end - now;

     var hours = Math.floor((remaining % _day) / _hour);
     var minutes = Math.floor((remaining % _hour) / _minute);
     var seconds = Math.floor((remaining % _minute) / _second);

     remain.innerHTML = ' ';
     remain.innerHTML += hours + 'h ';
     remain.innerHTML += minutes + 'm ';
     remain.innerHTML += (seconds + 1) + 's';

     var current = (full - (hours * 60) - minutes) / full * 100;
     progress.innerHTML = current.toFixed(1) + '%';
     progress.style.width = current + "%";

     setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
    }

    range.addEventListener('input', function() {
     var lwidth = range.value;
        progress.style.height = lwidth + "px";
    });

    updateTime();
}

   doInit();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#progress {
    height: 14px;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#remain {
    width: 100px;
    height: 14px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

#rng {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"> </div>
<div id="remain"></div>
<input id='rng' type="range" name="" min="10" max="20" value="15" step="1">
```