# How to activate function during input text change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the function 'name' to be activated and press the submit, while the input text changes.

How can i do it?

```
<form id="a"> 
  <input type="text" id="client_area" name="client_area" id="email" maxlength="5" size="5" onchange="name();">
  <input id="submit2" name="submit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Start"/>
</form>

<script>
  function name(){
    $("#submit2").click()
  });
);
</script>
```

*Also, can i add keyup too?

```
onchange="name();" onkeyup="name();"
```

Will it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is a reserved keyword to get the name of the function so you will get an error with `name is not a function` so you need to change the name of your function with `Name` or some other name:

```js
function Name(){
  $("#submit2").click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="a"> 
<input type="text" id="client_area" name="client_area" id="email" maxlength="5" size="5" onkeyup="Name()">
<input id="submit2" name="submit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Start"/>
</form>
```

This is how name is reserved as:

```js
var fn = function(){
  //some code
};

console.log(fn.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('#client_area').on('keyup change', function (e) {
    $("#submit2").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use onchange, id is enough;

```
<form id="a"> 
  <input type="text" id="client_area" name="client_area" id="email" maxlength="5" size="5" >
  <input id="submit2" name="submit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Start"/>
</form>
```

Use bind with jquery:

```
$('#client_area').bind('input', function() { 
    console.log("Submitted");
    $("#submit2").click();
});
```