# How to turn an input text-value into an object's property value in Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qr-code

I turned the input text-value into the inp1 var but once I want to call it inside the obj it doesn't work.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your text here" class="input fade-in" id="inp1" required>
```

```
 var inp1 = document.getElementById("inp1").value;

$(function(){
  $('#qrcode').qrcode({
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    text: "https://www.stackoverflow.com/" + inp1
  });
});
```

I expect the qrcode code to show the url + the text of the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code runs *once, when the page loads*. At that time, the input field is yet empty. Instead you probably want to update the qr code *whenever the input* changes. You need an event listener for that:

```
 $(function(){
   var input = $("#inp1"); // if you use jQuery, use it everywhere. Also retrieve the element when the document loaded

   input.on("change", function() { // listen for input changes
     $('#qrcode').qrcode({ // then update the qr code
       width: 150,
       height: 150,
       text: "https://www.stackoverflow.com/" + input.val(),
     });
   });
 });
```

You might want to consider using the [input event instead of the change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery) depending on your usecase.

Comment: The weird thing is that the [library page](https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/) has exactly the same example the OP is looking for

Comment: It's not uncommon for documentation to have errors in it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That example is working just fine and updating the qrcode as expected (I mean, I didn't actually scan it, but I saw it was changing)

Comment: @AlonEitan that's not the library that i'm using. That library doesn't work

Comment: Why does it give me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @codeworking Is it [this library](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode) then? Because if so, when you run `$('#qrcode').qrcode()` multiple times it adds a new qrcode and not replacing the old one. If it happens to you then you should change the code to `$('#qrcode').empty().qrcode({ .... });` (Note the `empty()` I added)

Comment: @AlonEitan you can find the library here https://codepen.io/rizopoulos/pen/KWjmQx

Comment: @codeworking Yep, so it has that problem that I was talking about, check [this fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjxYjG) You can see 2 qrcodes in the first wrapper and only one in the second one, because I added `empty()`

Comment: @AlonEitan alright it works! So basically it's the jquery.qrcode.js library. Where does the documentation talk about the empty() ?

Comment: @codeworking Nowhere, I just checked that library and noticed it, so I thought I will let you know in advance

Comment: Alright, thanks to both Alon and Jonas for your patience