# How to know input values changed in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have worked in filter option. Here more than one input fields are there. Like one select, input text, button click. All are under one class named "filter-option". When any one of these modified I have to alert the value inside a jQuery.

I have tried below code but not working.

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "filter-option", function() {
    alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: `.on('change', '.filter-option', ...)`???

Comment: I tried, but it is not working.

Comment: Well it should work, so if it's not working then you're doing something wrong. Without seeing more of your code, I can't help any further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the event to be fired whenever something is changed within the element then you could use the **change, keyup, blur** events.

```
$("body").on('change keyup blur', "filter-option", function() {
   alert('changed');
});
```

see also: [Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Keyup` function.

[Keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#SelectorName').keyup(function () { alert('text changed'); });
 });
</script>
```

OR using `keypress`

[keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

```
<input type="text">
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keypress(function(){
  alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

OR using `blur()`.

[blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

> `blur` gives you the change event only when you click on something else post entering the value in the input field.

```js
function yourFunction() {
  alert("clicked");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" onblur="yourFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  the best way is to store a flag in `data-attribute` of your form.

```
$(document).on("change", "#your_form_id :input", function () {
$("#your_form_id").data("changed", true);
alert("changed");
});
```

It will invoke change event of all the input fields inside the form tag.