# jQuery NaN Result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple calculator using jQuery and been stick with the NaN result for a few hours now. Not sure what i'm missing or where i made a mistake. Basically i just want to multiply 2 input fields.

A help would be great!

```js
var b = jQuery('input[name="mpfc-not-f"]').val();
var c = jQuery('input[name="atv-f"]').val();
total_rev = 0;
total_rev = Math.round(b * c);
totals_rev = total_rev.toString().replace(/(d)(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, "$1,");

jQuery(".over-total").text(totals_rev);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="0" name=" mpfc-not-f" class="mpfc-not"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="atv-f" class="atv"/>
<p class="over-total">0</p>
```

Comment: At the time your code runs, there's no value in the inputs. Notice also an extra space in the name of the first input, that's actually the reason causing NaN (empty strings are automatically converted to zero when using as an operand of  `*` operator).

Comment: omg, that extra space fixed the NaN issue. but i still get 0 as result. the initial value is 0 as indicated in the html code, wouldnt that set the initial value? also, ive added a document ready function

Comment: Umm ... yes, you're gettig `0 * 0`. If you want to do the math with user entered values, you need a button which can be clicked after user has entered the values.

Comment: I see, since the NaN issue has been fixed and i got a few more questions - is it alright to ask them here?

Comment: i guess to add the initial value that can be done thorugh html? value = "100"  but how can i make it auto calculate - as of now even i change the value in the text field the product is still the same. wont update

Comment: jQuery("input").on("change input", function(e) {

GOT ITT!! thanks yall!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
jquery(document).ready(() => {

var b = jQuery('input[name="mpfc-not-f"]').val();
var c = jQuery('input[name="atv-f"]').val();
total_rev = 0;
total_rev = Math.round(b * c);
totals_rev = total_rev.toString().replace(/(d)(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, "$1,");

jQuery(".over-total").text(totals_rev);


});
```

Comment: unfortunately still NaN

Comment: try to add parseInt() function on 'b' and 'c' variables. Then try to call ' let total_rev = '.

Comment: Get the Devtools up with F12 and put a break in the code and see what's happening as b and c are loaded. One of them must not be getting a numeric value, like ""?.

Comment: Also, as @Teemu said, this will all run as soon as the doc is loaded. What are the values in the inputs at that point? Are you sure you don't want to delay the calculation until some data has been entered? In which case you'll need to put all that code into a function and create a way to trigger its activation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function mul(){
  var b = jQuery('input[name="mpfc-not-f"]').val();
  var c = jQuery('input[name="atv-f"]').val();
  total_rev = 0;
  total_rev = Math.round(b * c);
  totals_rev = total_rev.toString().replace(/(d)(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, "$1,");
  jQuery(".over-total").text(totals_rev);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="0" name="mpfc-not-f" class="mpfc-not"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="atv-f" class="atv"/>
<p class="over-total">0</p>
<button onclick="mul()">Multiply</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps You

```js
function doMath(){
  let multiply_result =  $("#numberA").val() * $("#numberB").val();
  console.log(multiply_result);
  return multiply_result;
}

$(".number").change(function(){
  let result = doMath();
  jQuery(".over-total").text(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="numberA" value="0" name=" mpfc-not-f" class="mpfc-not number"/>
<input type="text" id="numberB" value="0" name="atv-f" class="atv number"/>
<p class="over-total">0</p>
</div>
```